# I installed Xampp on Windows 8. When I try to start MySql in XAMPP control panel I have the following message and MySql does not start

Tags: php, mysql, apache

[image]
Remove prev. installed and install new than start mysql . but when start next day same facing problem, I already check Skype(Not start)
How to slove problem

Comment: Please post log at here.

Answer (score 0):

Run a `netstat` and see what program on port 3306 (MySQL default) is using. Typically this is Skype or other similar programs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the port of MySQL. Just go to
`config -> Services and Port Setting -> MySQL -> Main Port`
It is default 3306 change it to 3308 and try again.